# npm run serve gets hang on 98% while building

Tags: npm, vuetify.js

I'm working on a project using vuetify. I was using "npm run serve" command to build and run a live server. it was working all good until all of sudden my project stopped building. every time i try running the command "npm run serve" it builds and hangs on 98% without throwing an error.

i tried npm install. npm build none of these fix the issue

in my terminal i run this command and the result is as follows:

```
npm run serve
rep-vuetify@0.1.0 serve /Users/Desktop/rg21-vuetify/rep-vuetify vue-cli-service serve
INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin
```

IT hangs on 98% and don't do anything after this, been stuck on this step for whole week if some one can help me.

Comment: Have you tried to remove/cleanup `node_modules` directory and start `npm run serve` again?

Comment: Yes and I get the same thing, gets stuck on 98%. i'm not sure how to track down the error and fix this

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules and the package-lock.json. Then npm install and run serve

Comment: i tried that, it says: command not found following with this message: Failed at the rep-vuetify@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

Comment: I am also having this issue. Please have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 19):

I have same problem stuck in 98%.

> 98% after emitting CopyPlugin

In my case, I recheck again my code, and I found my import path is invalid, something like :

```
import { myComponent } from ''
```

After fix the code, It works again.

Answer (score 2):

I my case the problem is a empty require

```
getBackground() {
  return `url(${require("")})`;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Vue**, if you have multiple HTML elements of a **component/view** not contained within a single element (eg. this DIV) the building will froze/halt unexpectedly.

Get sure to have all items contained within a section, div, etc.

Probably, NPM has nothing to do with this particular problem.

```
<template>
  <div class="contain-all-stuff">
    <!-- Anything inside this one single DIV container -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are installed ESLint.

Try to run "npm run lint" command before you run "npm run serve"

it worked for me.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update you NPM to the latest version and run your CLI as admin if you are using windows I have faced the same problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of NPM you are using?
I was getting the same issue with **node version 12.6.0**.
After **node version** updated to the **12.9.1**, the issue is resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message, but I resolved it.
In my case, I just change different branch. after that, I change back the original branch, then it doesn't work when I run "npm run serve".

**The problem is all import paths are case sensitive!**

So when I change to the old branch, it changes my directory name to uppercase letters( before I use uppercase directory name). But the latest branch I already changed to lowercase letters for directory  name.

For example, if your import like below:

`component: () => import('@/views/test/Test'),`

then you should check the directory's name and file's name must be the same uppercase letters and lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem past 2020, check everything in your Vuex index.js page and ensure that all the paths to you modules are correct. One of mine was incorrect and it took me an hour to figure it out. It might not be empty, so a search like suggested above will not help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.. but the % the build was freezing was variable.
For me it was one stupid > that was missing in a closing div-tag..
Just wondering why I did not get an error on that :s