# 98% after emitting CopyPlugin when npm run server in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, npm, server, vue-cli

After I completed the todolist app that can be clicked on the submit button with handleSubmit function, and I want to add another function which can trigger handleSubmit function by clicking Enter button on the keyboard.

And then the error massage appear...
some information for you to know more about my environment, if you need more info, please tell me.THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

**init by Vue-cli**

## package.json

```
  {
  "name": "vue-todolist",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}

# Error Message #
WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                                                         9:10:17 ├F10: PM┤

98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                      9:10:18 ├F10: PM┤

error  in ./src/components/Todolist.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected "," (46:6)

  44 |           }
  45 |         }
> 46 |       },
     |       ^
  47 |     },
  48 |   };
  49 | 


 @ ./src/components/Todolist.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-277 1:293-296 1:298-572 1:298-572
 @ ./src/components/Todolist.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://172.20.10.3:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Comment: clearly here a syntax error. Have a look again or attach some relevant code to your post :)

Comment: thank you for your reply, i will check it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm run serve gets hang on 98% while building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603711/npm-run-serve-gets-hang-on-98-while-building)